# Chart total return of mutual fund vs. stock with dividends reinvested?

Tags: stock-analysis, dividend-reinvestment

Using common charting software, how can I best compare total returns of a mutual fund vs. total return of a stock, with dividend reinvestment (*DRIP*) in each case?

Frequently the easy to get charts show price alone, without regard to dividend payment.

Ideally I'd like to find a charting service where I can enter my marginal tax rate for post-tax effects, subtract out any load or sales charge, and compare with a total return version of an index (e.g. S&P 500 TR).

Answer (score 5):

I found this DRIP calculator http://www.dividendchannel.com/drip-returns-calculator/ at a website called "Dividend Channel". 
[image: Total return with DRIP]

However it does not account for tax loss (e.g. the taxes due on gains).